# How to make a php script(app) accessible to all wordpress subdomains in a wordpress multisite configuration?

Tags: multisite, localhost

i have a wordpress 5.8.1 installation on Windows 10 with a multisite configuration locally (localhost) and i want to access a php app in an app folder from all subdomains i created. (There are three at total)
e.g: 
localhost/site1
localhost/site2
localhost/site3

What i want to do is for every site (site1,site2,site3) is that they can access the app folder
e.g:

```
localhost/site1/app
localhost/site2/app
localhost/site3/app
```

How do i procede to do so? Should i put the app folder at wordpress' root folder or another folder? And what should i do so that every subdomain has access to the app folder? I really don't know how to procede so that it works like i want. If anyone can point me to the right direction this would help me very much.

here's what i added to my default wordpress wp-config file:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

and here's my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I hope that i'm on the right track, if anyone can help me this would be good.